# how can i add event on pressing tab bar in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a react native app in which i am using react navigation v3. I want to create an event on pressing a particular tab bar. On my home tab bar i have a barcode scanner. When the user scans, the app directs to different tab with the barcode data setting the data to async storage.But when i try to scan again it goes blank.

So, i want to create an event on which i can clear the async storage when the user goes to home tab to scan again. How can i add that event on home tab bar?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code it will help you,

```
import {NavigationEvents} from "react-navigation";


<NavigationEvents
      onWillFocus={payload => console.log('will focus',payload)}
      onDidFocus={payload => console.log('did focus',payload)}
      onWillBlur={payload => console.log('will blur',payload)}
      onDidBlur={payload => console.log('did blur',payload)}
    />
```

`NavigationEvents` component you can added in your render method of page where you want to track event of users, and handle like `AsyncStorage` and whatever action you want.

Only add one event if you don't need all

For more detail you may visit [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html)

Thank you

Comment: I have done something like this. But i get nothing on the console when i do this  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-u4rxpr?embed=1&file=index.js  ...What am i missing here? @Hardik Virani

Comment: Really sorry for that. Here's my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-62rejg?embed=1&file=index.js  @HardikVirani

Comment: you need to code `<NavigationEvents
      onWillFocus={payload => console.log('will focus', payload)}
      onDidFocus={payload => console.log('did focus',payload)}
      onWillBlur={payload => console.log('will blur',payload)}
      onDidBlur={payload => console.log('did blur',payload)}
    />` inside render return

Answer (score 1):

You could listeners to the [navigation lifecycle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) events.

It is fairly straight forward to set up. Here is an example of how to set it up in your screen.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Screen2 extends React.Component {

  // willFocus - the screen will focus
  // didFocus - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
  // willBlur - the screen will be unfocused
  // didBlur - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
  componentDidMount () {
    // add listener 
    this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.willFocusAction);
    this.didFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', this.didFocusAction);
    this.willBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', this.willBlurAction);
    this.didBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('didBlur', this.didBlurAction);
  }

  componentWillUmount () {
    // remove listener
    this.willFocusSubscription.remove()
    this.didFocusSubscription.remove();
    this.willBlurSubscription.remove();
    this.didBlurSubscription.remove();
  }

  willBlurAction = () => {
    console.log('willBlur Screen', new Date().getTime())
  }

  didBlurAction = () => {
    console.log('didBlur Screen', new Date().getTime());
  }

  didFocusAction = () => {
    console.log('didFocus Screen', new Date().getTime());
  }

  willFocusAction = () => {
    console.log('willFocus Screen', new Date().getTime());
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Screen</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

You don't need to add all the listeners, only the ones that you require. 
Most likely you will want to clear your value from `AsyncStorage` inside the `willFocus` event. That way it occurs before the screen has come into focus.